# Like search on indexed properties is taking more time in cypher query of Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

There is a relationship between Entity and Addess node. Entity has unique key constraint on eid and Address has unique key constraint on addressLocation.
I have millions of node for Entity and Address. Exact seach query works fine and here is the query -

```
match(e:Entity)-[r]->(a:Address) where a.addressLocation="ABC XYZ" return r
```

But like search query taking too much time that lead to ReadTimeOutException. Here is the query -

```
match(e:Entity)-[r]->(a:Address) where a.addressLocation=~".*(?i)ABC XYZ.*" return r
```

Can anybody tell me what i should do to get like search result as quick as exact search result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query is using an index lookup (on `Address.addressLocation`):

```
match(e:Entity)-[r]->(a:Address) where a.addressLocation="ABC XYZ" return r
```

The second query is using a regular expression which is not able to use the index and is therefore not very performant:

```
match(e:Entity)-[r]->(a:Address) where a.addressLocation=~".*(?i)ABC XYZ.*" return r
```

Cypher has three string comparison operators `STARTS WITH`, `ENDS WITH` and `CONTAINS`. `STARTS WITH` will make use of an index so this query should be performant:

```
MATCH (e:Entity)-[r]->(a:Addres)
WHERE a.addressLocation STARTS WITH "ABC XYZ"
RETURN r
```

`ENDS WITH` and `CONTAINS` (which is really what you want) do not currently use an index, however in Neo4j 3.0 both will use an index. There is a milestone version of 3.0 available [on the download page](http://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/) if you'd like to try it.

Comment: Thanks William, it would really be helpful.

Comment: Do you have any idea when Neo4j 3.0 stable relase will be rolled out